# TypeError in enum validation while saving an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have an enum on which I am trying to add validation but it is giving me a type error that the array is not a symbol nor a string when I am saving any record in the database. Here is the code:

```
validates :animal, inclusion: { in: %w(DOG, CAT), message: '%{value} is not a valid animal' }
enum animal: [:DOG, :CAT]
```

I am getting the following error: 
TypeError: ["DOG", "CAT"] is not a symbol nor a string

Comment: How do you test these methods? In the console or on a webpage? What values do in input? Please show the corresponding log file entries and the full error message including the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord `eunm` do not need a separate validation to check the inclusion. Just remove that custom validation. Rails will throw an error by default when you use a value that is not part of the enum values list.

Tested with Rails 5.2.2:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum animal: [:DOG, :CAT]
end
```

Test:

```
p = Person.new
=> #<Person ...>

p.animal = :DOG # this works
p.animal = :FROG

Traceback (most recent call last):
ArgumentError ('FROG' is not a valid animal)
```